# Receiving wrong value

Tags: excel, vba, memory

At the begin of my macro, I call this macro that changes all commas to dots.

```
Sub commaToDot()

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Oficial").Activate

 Columns("B:B").Select
     Selection.Replace What:=",", Replacement:=".", LookAt:=xlPart, _
     SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
         ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

It works, as I can see in my data. It replaces all commas to dots from the column B.

Later in my code, I copy some of the values (which had COMMAS and now have DOTS) to other cells, but the values appear with COMMAS.

Why? I am thinking there is some memory misbehavior, but I have no idea how to work around it. Any suggestions?

Comment: why don't you attach the other part of your code ('later in my code')? what kind of values are you dealing with- numbers or text?

Comment: cause it´s irrelevant, I am sure. I have somethink like "4,3", which I replace for "4.3" with that code above. Later, I only do Cell(2,1) = Cell(4,1)  (not real index)

Comment: I seems to be relevant- later you copy value from Cell D1 to B1 (but you did replacement in column B). If there is anything in D1 with comma then you have it back in B1. That is the problem.

Comment: Let me be as clearest as possible: after I replace these commas, I do many other things and then I check the column before the one I have manipulated. If I removed commans from B, I check A: if my condition is true, I copy value from B to a new blank cell.

Comment: That is the line which copies the value: 
Worksheets("Email").Cells(contadorOr, colunaOrigem + 5).Value = Worksheets("Oficial").Cells(contadorDes, colunaDestino + 1).Value

And here (Worksheets("Oficial").Cells(contadorDes, colunaDestino + 1).Value) are the cells which were manipulated (where I called commaToDot)

Comment: My guess this is an International formatting problem.  For example, if your Windows Regional Settings are Portuguese, or some other language that is using the comma as a decimal, then your problem likely relates to your VBA routine doing something to cause the destination cell to interpret the "dotted number" as a number and not as a text string.

Comment: I believe you are right @RonRosenfeld. If I change the destination cell to TEXT before I run the script, it works just fine. This is not the best solution, but it solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I will post this as an answer so you can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess this is an International formatting problem. For example, if your Windows Regional Settings are Portuguese, or some other language that is using the comma as a decimal, then your problem likely relates to your VBA routine doing something to cause the destination cell to interpret the "dotted number" as a number and not as a text string.

To force Excel to interpret the "pasted" value as a string, probably the simplest method would be to precede the value to be copied with a single quote mark.  This will show up in the formula bar, but not in the cell or any printouts.  You could also pre-format the cell as text, but that may not be as desireable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably resides in the fact that you have different formats for your columns. Make sure your columns are properly formatted.

To force the contents of a column to be a number rather than text, try the following (in case changing column formatting doesn't have the desired effect right away) :

```
lastRow = Cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
For x = 1 to lastRow
    cells(x,1) = cells(x,1) + 0  'or you could do cells(x,1) = cells(x,1) / 1
Next
```

This will loop through all the cells of column 1 and force these to be a number.

Comment: Actually, doesn´t matter to me if the value is a number or string. But it´s weird: if I copy manually the value to the new column, it appears with dot. If my script copies the same value, it appears with comma.