# Excel to change the content of a selection

Tags: vba, excel

I hope someone can help me with a macro for some text manipulation in Excel.

**Question:**

How can I change the content of selected cells (even whole columns/rows) by using a macro? How should that macro look like?

There are some rules that I am looking to follow in the process:

- Let's presume that we have the following content in the cells A1-A5:

  A1: some text, aZx

  A2: Some OtHer text, Kvfr

  A3: Random TEXT ,mot

  A4: Text text, text, LPK

  A5: Any other random text ,KKj

-> After selecting the cells A1-A5 or even the whole column A and then running the macro, the result should be:

```
A1: Azx some text

A2: Kvfr Some OtHer text

A3: Mot Random TEXT

A4: Lpk Text text, text

A5: Kkj Any other random text
```

Basically I have to take the groups like `", aZx"`; `", Kvfr"`; `",mot"` ; `", LPK"` ; `",KKj"` , transform them to `"Azx"`; `"Kvfr"`; `"Mot"`; `"Lpk"`; `"Kkj"`and then move them in front of the whole text in that cell.

These groups of letters can be hard coded in the macro.

---

My first idea is to put all the expressions that I am interested in arrays, like this:

```
Dim basicExpr(1 To 5) As String
basicExpr(1) = ", aZx"
basicExpr(2) = ", Kvfr"
basicExpr(3) = ",mot"
basicExpr(4) = ", LPK"
basicExpr(5) = ",KKj"

Dim replaceExpr(1 To 5) As String
replaceExpr(1) = "Azx "
replaceExpr(2) = "Kvfr "
replaceExpr(3) = "Mot "
replaceExpr(4) = "Lpk "
replaceExpr(5) = "Kkj "
```

Then I want to loop through all the selected cells and check for values from `basicExpr`(also check if the value is at the end of the string) and process the cell accordingly.

```
Set cellRange = Application.Selection
For Each Cell In cellRange
```

At this point I'm stuck as I am not sure how to select with `instrrev`from the last comma to the end of the string, then title case it and move it to the front of the string.

Comment: So you want to find the text after the last comma, move it to the beginning of the string, capitalize it according to title case, and keep the rest of the string unchanged?

Comment: Then `instrrev` will find the last comma, `strconv` will convert to title case, and `for each` will loop through `selection.cells`.

Comment: As I am a rookie when it comes to VBA and excel, it's quite difficult to wrap around a macro to do that. I have documented the particular use of those functions yet putting them together is not so easy at the moment :(

Comment: Any ideas on how to get this going? I've started something and posted it as an answer below yet now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always want to move the text that is found after the comma, then this code will do that.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub rearrangeTheText()

Dim cellRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim positionFound As Integer
Dim theWholeText As String
Dim theSmallPart As String

Const TEXT_TO_FIND As String = ","

    Set cellRange = Application.Selection

    For Each cell In cellRange
        theWholeText = CStr(cell.Value)
        ' Look for last TEXT_TO_FIND
        positionFound = InStrRev(theWholeText, TEXT_TO_FIND, , vbTextCompare)
        If positionFound > 0 Then
            ' Get the text that is after TEXT_TO_FIND
            theSmallPart = Trim$(StrConv(Mid$(theWholeText, positionFound + Len(TEXT_TO_FIND)), vbProperCase))
            ' Delete the text and TEXT_TO_FIND from the end
            theWholeText = Trim$(Mid$(theWholeText, 1, positionFound - 1))
            ' Add the text to the front, separated by a space
            theWholeText = theSmallPart & Space(1) & theWholeText
            ' Update the cell
            cell.Value = theWholeText
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 =PROPER(RIGHT(A1,3))&" "&LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-5)
```

The 5 is based on your example with ", aZx" at the end - if this changes you will have to edit it. No macro, just a function in a cell.

Comment: That 5 will not always be there as the content of the cell will always vary. At the same time the macro needs to be applied to a selection of cells.

Comment: So, in your example you show comma then space then 3 characters that you are interested in. How does the combination of those 5 change? the length can be any - unless you hit 255 I think...

Comment: That's because at the end we can have more than 3 letters, it can be 4 or 5 even and the position of the comma is not expected to be always like that, there can also be spaces involved like: ", KvFr"; " ,KvfR" or other combinations.

Comment: Then you could look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316063/vba-receiving-wrong-value/21316768#21316768 and replace "cells(x,1)" with an expression based on what GSerg put forward.

Comment: It's a good place to start, I am still documenting on how to put together everything that Gserg suggested. I am not particularly a programmer yet it's very important for me to make this macro work.